# Are there any non-NT examples, from the Koine Greek, of an author using the phrase "truly, truly?"

Tags: greek, hebrew, word-study, hebrew-bible

I've read different interpretations of the significance of Jesus' use of "truly, truly," in the Gospels. From the very pious and serious, to an argument that Jesus is basically cracking jokes, like when a comedian says, "Seriously - SERIOUSLY!" followed by an over the top statement; or, in a tongue in cheek, manner - or, even hyperbole.

Now, smart as we all are, and, valid as I'm everyone's opinion is, I really want to find it in some writing from antiquity, if possible, to help gauge the contextual usage.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here. Please be sure to take the [site tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up on how this site is a [little different](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives#803) than other sites around the web. We typically ask people to cite a specific Biblical passage in a question, if you could add one example. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. "Truly Truly" is used as an affirmation in **[Nehemiah 8:6]** "And Ezra blessed YHVH, The-Great God, and all the people answered, **"Amen, Amen,"** with the uplifting of their hands, and they bent their heads and prostrated themselves to the Lord on their faces to the ground." ( וַיְבָ֣רֶךְ עֶזְרָ֔א אֶת־יְהֹוָ֥ה הָאֱלֹהִ֖ים הַגָּד֑וֹל וַיַּֽעֲנ֨וּ כָל־הָעָ֜ם אָמֵ֚ן | אָמֵן֙ בְּמֹ֣עַל יְדֵיהֶ֔ם וַיִּקְּד֧וּ וַיִּשְׁתַּֽחֲווּ֛ לַיהֹוָ֖ה אַפַּ֥יִם אָֽרְצָה )

- "Amen Amen" **אָמֵ֥ן אָמֵֽן** is translated **"Truly Truly"** in English.

[ https://www.sefaria.org/Nehemiah.8.6?with=all&lang=bi ]

---

Also a similar phrase is found in [Psalm 89:53] "Blessed is YHVH forever. **Amen and Amen**." ( בָּר֖וּךְ יְהֹוָ֥ה לְ֜עוֹלָ֗ם אָ֘מֵ֥ן וְאָמֵֽן)

- "Amen ve-Amen" **אָמֵ֥ן וְאָמֵֽן** is translated **"Truly and Truly"** in English.

[ https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.89.53?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en ]

- You will notice Psalm 89:[53] of the Tanakh is listed in English bibles as Psalm 89:[52].

Comment: The question is about the use of a phrase in non-biblical Greek, though I suppose you are suggesting Jesus (as reported by John) is using a Hebrew or Aramaic set phrase.  As a passing note, the Septuagint seems to use one ἀμήν (amen) in [Nehemiah 8:6](https://www.septuagint.bible/nehemiah/-/asset_publisher/l5tBRlYCzctt/content/neemias-kephalaio-8) and a different γένοιτο γένοιτο (may it be ×2) at the end of [Psalm 88/89](https://www.septuagint.bible/psalms/-/asset_publisher/TKUcY6iZbwnU/content/psalmos-88)